# Overriding Devise Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

I'm building an application that takes an admin and a company in one form and connects the two. The connection part is setup with a belongs_to relationship (Admin belongs to the company).

The problem I have is that I'm using Devise and it automatically takes all my params and tries to make a user. The thing is, in the params, the company is just a name string. So I need to build the company, then send (presumably) the company_id to Devise, or set it up myself afterwards.

This is what I've tried in the Admin:RegistrationController.

```
def create
  @company = Company.create(name: params[:admin][:company])
  super
  @admin.company = @company
end
```

This fails to create the Admin, and Devise returns the error "The Company must exist". And is also obviously rather hacky (or at least feels that way).

What should I do here, and what is the best practice? Thanks!

Comment: I'd look into using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :company`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create override one new file in folder  app/controllers/admins/registration_controller.rb 
and add this command below (some part is devise standard command)

```
class Admins::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    @company = Company.create(name: params[:admin][:company])
    # resource is standard
    resource.company   = @company
    resource.save
  end

end
```

Comment: You can do that without copy-pasting the entire implementation.

Comment: This one actually does exactly what I wanted... although it seems to override the signing in stage... is there an easy way to get it to sign in once completed?

Comment: I found it, it's just a devise method, `sign_in :admin, resource`

Comment: After editing this still pretty much clobbers the entire implementation. If anything its worse than the original. Don't do this.

Comment: Hi Max - can you explain what is so bad? It just looks like you're using a devise method - build_resource - and then adding the company after it's made... what's going on here that's terrible? Cheers...

Answer (score 1):

You can override `#build_resource` to hook into the [original `#create` implementation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/e3a00b27d19ba995891d7dd92394fe2900a789c2/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb):

```
class Admin:RegistrationController < ::Devise::RegistrationsController
  def build_resource(hash = {})
    super
    if action_name == "create"
      self.resource.company ||= Company.create 
    end
  end
end
```

However from a UX perspective it might be a better idea to let the user select existing companies through a select or use [accepts_nested_attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to let the user fill in fields for the company.

You could also make the association optional and let the user fill in the company details after registration.

> what is the best practice?

Whatever way accomplishes the requirements on time.